# Remove last four characters in string that's part of url?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code:

```
<a href="<%= this.ResolveUrl("Search.aspx?id=" + lblGraphicNameValue.Text) %>" target="_blank">Search Related</a>
```

I want to take the text value of lblGraphicNameValue and remove the last four characters.  Can I do this, and keep it inline?  Or is this something I should do in the code behind?

Thanks!

Comment: Tip: use HttpUtility.UrlEncode() for encoding the label text and HttpUtility.UrlDecode() for decoding it when you want to read from query string.

Comment: I get really suspicious when I see questions like this. Why 4 exactly? What if your string is less than 4 characters long? Why a URL? Are you trying to extract components of a URL; like scheme, port number, or query attributes? .NET has `Uri` methods to extract components of URLs without counting characters.

Comment: We have a system here where a graphic# is a string that looks like this 'XX-XXXXXX-XXX'.  There is a search page in this system where a user can type in the graphic# to search for it in the database.  On another page the user's wanted the ability to search for the 'base' graphic number, which looks like this 'XX-XXXXXX', basically the graphic number minus the last four characters.  The graphic number appears in a field on that particular page, so the users wanted a link to click that would send the 'base' graphic number to the search page without them having to exit their current page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
<a href="<%= this.ResolveUrl("Search.aspx?id=" + lblGraphicNameValue.Text.Substring(0, lblGraphicNameValue.Text.Length - 4) %>" target="_blank">Search Related</a>
```

or also this:

```
<a href="<%= this.ResolveUrl("Search.aspx?id=" + lblGraphicNameValue.Text.Remove(lblGraphicNameValue.Text.Length - 4) %>" target="_blank">Search Related</a>
```

I'm not sure, I have no experience with ASP.NET though so I don't know if it allows arbitrary code.

Comment: Rather `lblGraphicNameValue.Text.Length - 4` ?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter My typo. Fixed.

Comment: Your second option worked perfectly for me.  I'll mark it as answer as soon as timer is up!  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc.aspx) method:

```
lblGraphicNameValue.Text.Remove(lblGraphicNameValue.Text.Length - 4)
```